# php friends table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with this for hours so please help me.
This is my users table

```
id | username | last_activity(timestamp for online system)
```

And this is my friends table

```
id | uid | fid
```

What I want is to order the output by **last_activity**
My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT fid FROM friends WHERE uid='$user_id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `INNER JOIN` to join the two tables:

```
SELECT f.fid 
FROM friends f 
INNER JOIN users u 
ON u.id = f.id 
ORDER BY u.last_activity DESC
```

Always make sure you type out a real JOIN clause as some ways are old and getting more and more unsupported.

Read more here:
[INNER JOIN on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT f.fid FROM f.friends
LEFT JOIN users u ON f.uid = u.id
WHERE uid=$user_id
ORDER BY u.last_activity DESC
```

Comment: You need to join to the users table to get last_activity.

Comment: np your JOIN needs to come before the WHERE clause, though.

Comment: lol, thanks, fixed. together we'll nail this difficult problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
SELECT f.fid AS fid
FROM friends f, users u
WHERE f.uid = u.id AND f.uid = $user_id
ORDER BY u.last_activity DESC
```

I assume your problem is that `fid` is on one table, but the ordering criterion `last_activity` is on another table. The goal of this query is to `JOIN` each row in the `friends` table with the corresponding row in the `users` table (via the `WHERE` clause).

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming `uid` in friends table is `foreign key references to id` in users
>   table. so using INNER JOIN you can retrieve your desired results.

```
      SELECT f.fid
      FROM friends f INNER JOIN user_tb u 
      ON u.id = f.uid
      WHERE f.uid = '$user_id'
      ORDER BY u.last_activity DESC;
```